# Amsterdam Shapefile

Tags: r, shapefile

I am looking to make a point data map of Airbnb listings in Amsterdam. 
I would like to be able to plot the data onto a .shp (shapefile) but am having great difficulty finding a shapefile of the outline of the city and its regions.

Anyone know where I can find a shapefile of Amsterdam?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The city of Amsterdam is very active in providing open data to providers. Geodata can be found at their [geodata portal](https://maps.amsterdam.nl/open_geodata/).